# Compile error on Animation in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am new with Windows Phone animation and using the below code but it give me compile error:

'System.Windows.Controls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'BeginAnimation' and no extension method 'BeginAnimation' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Which reference I am missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = 30;
        da.To = 100;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        button1.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, da);            
    }
```

Comment: WP7 != WPF.  Which one are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIElement.BeginAnimation method does not exist in WP7. Instead, you will need to create a storyboard as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var sb = new Storyboard();
  var db = CreateDoubleAnimation(30, 100,
         button1, Button.HeightProperty, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
  sb.Children.Add(db);
  sb.Begin();
}

private static DoubleAnimation CreateDoubleAnimation(double from, double to, 
      DependencyObject target, object propertyPath, TimeSpan duration)
{
  var db = new DoubleAnimation();
  db.To = to;
  db.From = from;
  db.Duration = duration;
  Storyboard.SetTarget(db, target);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(db, new PropertyPath(propertyPath));
  return db;
}
```